# How to solve the Atom VsCode FTP error?

Tags: node.js, ftp, visual-studio-code, sftp, atom-editor

I use the ftp/sftp-development package in atom and vscode.
When I tried to sync the file in server, they all show that

```
Ftp-sync: sync error: Error: All configured authentication methods failed
```

config file exists well. everything goes well, the problem just happened.

Comment: For sftp: if you have saved remote server rsa key, ftp-sync will not use password. Use ssh key auth instead password.

Answer (score 0):

Triple-check your login and password/private key - they are *likely* wrong.

When checking, mind hidden special symbols.

Comment: It's about the ssh RSA public key

Comment: @T.Cheng Updated answer.